# Como comparar se a div com event click possui uma classe semelhante a outra div selecionada?

Tags: jquery, eventos-do-mouse

Tenho um conjunto de div's com event click em jQuery. Não estou sabendo como comparar as div's clicadas se possuem a mesma classe de icon.
tenho uma div já selecionada, se o usuário clicar em outra div no mesmo container quero aplicar outro event caso ela tenha ícones semelhantes comparando as classes dos ícones se eles são iguais.

Ex: 
Div1 selecionada tem o `<i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>`
Div2 ao ser clicada deverar compara com a div1 se ela também possui `<i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>` porém não sei como realizar essa comparação em jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer utilizando **hasClass** no evento de click de cada tag `i`, por exemplo;

```js
$('i').on('click', function() {
  var icone = $(this);
  
  if(icone.hasClass('fa-bicycle') == true){
    console.log('Tem a classe');
  } else {
    console.log('Não tem a classe');
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i></div>
<div><i class="fa fa-home"></i></div>
<div><i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i></div>
```

Comment: Tenho vários icones, teria que criar um array com o nome deles e inteirar cada um para testar a condicional?

Comment: Para te dar uma resposta mais correta, precisaria ver o html. Mas o **on click** já está pegando todos os ícones que vc tiver na página e comparando com a condição.

Comment: `<ul class="deck">
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
            </li>
        </ul>`
Tenho este exemplo, existem pares de classe repetidos que ao serem clicadas iriam fechar ou dar hide, porém como comparar se as classes são repetidas?

Comment: Wemerson, tá meio confuso de entender, vc diz classes das **li**?